# pip install is not working giving me error building wheel for lxml (setup.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, lxml, python-wheel

I get the following problem when trying to install `dronekit` module in python.

```sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install dronekit
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting dronekit
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/dronekit/dronekit-2.9.2-py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting monotonic>=1.3
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/monotonic/monotonic-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
Collecting pymavlink>=2.2.20
  Using cached pymavlink-2.4.15-cp36-cp36m-linux_armv7l.whl
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.6.3.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Collecting future
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/future/future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl (491 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... \^canceled
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: its freezing while building wheel for lxml(setup.py)... and nothing happens

Comment: Try adding a `-v` option to (hopefully) get more useful output https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/ and see where it's getting stuck.